# Having trouble setting up a reaction role embed for discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, embed

I'm a newbie at coding, so please do guide me through this process :)

ive just started coding a discord bot using discord.js, and im currently setting up a reaction role embed. The bot sends the embed out and reacts to it successfully, but only gives out 2 of the 5 roles specified.

```
module.exports = {
name: 'pingroles',
description: 'setting up reaction role embed',
async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
    const channel = '838758430167793674';
    const GiveawayPing = message.guild.roles.cache.get("837523359234392094");
    const EventsPing = message.guild.roles.cache.get("834707014763413506");
    const ChatRevive = message.guild.roles.cache.get("834720883800932352");
    const PartnerPing = message.guild.roles.cache.get("834703744351731782");
    const PollsPing = message.guild.roles.cache.get("837540284723757106");
    
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("816988982587555871");


    const GiveawayPingEmoji = guild.emojis.cache.get("855257836106678282");
    const EventsPingEmoji= '';
    const ChatReviveEmoji = guild.emojis.cache.get("837426948489478185");
    const PartnerPingEmoji = guild.emojis.cache.get("855264361375727616")
    const PollsPingEmoji = ''

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#add8e6')
        .setTitle ('Ping Roles')
        .setDescription ("React to get your roles\n\n"
            + `${GiveawayPingEmoji} for Giveaway Ping\n`
            + `${EventsPingEmoji} for Events Ping\n`
            + `${ChatReviveEmoji} for Chat Revive Ping\n`
            + `${PartnerPingEmoji} for Partner Ping\n`
            + `${PollsPingEmoji} for Polls Ping`);


    let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
    messageEmbed.react(GiveawayPingEmoji);
    messageEmbed.react(EventsPingEmoji);
    messageEmbed.react (ChatReviveEmoji);
    messageEmbed.react(PartnerPingEmoji);
    messageEmbed.react(PollsPingEmoji);
    
    client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
        if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
        if (user.bot) return;
        if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

        if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
            if (reaction.emoji.name === GiveawayPingEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(GiveawayPing);
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === EventsPingEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(EventsPing);
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === ChatReviveEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(ChatRevive);
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === PartnerPingEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(PartnerPing);
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === PollsPingEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(PollsPing); 
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }

    });

    client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
        if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
        if (user.bot) return;
        if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

        if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
            if (reaction.emoji.name === GiveawayPingEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(GiveawayPing);
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === EventsPingEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(EventsPing);
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === ChatReviveEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(ChatRevive);
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === PartnerPingEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(PartnerPing);
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === PollsPingEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(PollsPing); 
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }

    });        

    
}
 
}
```

The only 2 roles that are given out currently are events ping and polls ping, and i don't really know why the bot is not giving out roles for the other reactions and what i can do to make it work.
I based the code on a youtube tutorial that ive looked through, then tweaked it a little to better suit my purposes

Thanks for the help in advance!

Edit: ive followed @typicalninja's advice and watched the tutorial, but i realised that the code provided was kind of similar to mine, and am still not able to identify the problem. However, I did realise that the affected roles are those that use a custom discord emoji, meaning that I am only able to give out roles to the 2 reactions that use default windows emojis (gamenight and polls).

I'd like to know if there is any way in which I am able to alter my code so that I would be able to set up the reaction roles using custom emojis (there aren't many tutorials out there that teach this.

Thank you again in advance!

Comment: before anything, why are you nesting events inside of your commands?

Comment: your adding 2 event listeners  (`messageReactionRemove and messageReactionAdd`) everytime a reaction role gets created, and you have a max 10 event listener limit of 10
for every event, you should set this up with a database, (if single server, a simple one will do)
and add these events in the main file, and check the reaction with your database

Comment: @TYPICALNINJA ive tested it out with a server, and it worked well when there were only just 2 reaction options. it was only when i began adding more than 2 reactions that the code began not working.

Comment: @TYPICALNINJA regarding your comment about nesting events, im not too sure about what you mean as i pretty much just took the code from an online tutorial. please do guide me through as i am kinda new to this. thanks

Comment: 1# this is not permanent once you restart the bot, you will not be able to get a role from these reactions role you setup using this

2# soon, after using this method and creating several reactions roles, you would get a warning about max memory listeners and "about a possible memory leak"
A your creating multiple listeners for 1 event, if its avoidable you should use only 1 listener for each event

Comment: If you want, i will leave a link to the tutorial I learned from ( 2 year's ago so might be bit outdated) about reaction roles with discord.js, which does what i said

Comment: hmm tho, i think it was with mongoDB (event though mongo is good, idk about how beginners friendly)

Comment: @TYPICALNINJA id appreciate if u could leave a link to the tutorial. also, do you have any suggestions on improving the code? or would i have to redo a new one?

Comment: i would suggest redoing this part of the code, tbh it could be made better, but since your beginner you shouldn't try to do more than what you know about

Here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pP6omkdLfGE&t=454s

adapt your code to his code, ex he uses bot instead of `client`but both are same, he just defined his `bot`

he also has a basic command handler, so you should adapt to your command handler

Comment: @TYPICALNINJA ill try it out, thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @TYPICALNINJA ive watched the tutorial, and i have edited my post based on the current difficulties that i still face.. hoping that youll be able to guide me through. thanks :)

Comment: ill take a look a guide you in the morning, now i have to sleep,

Comment: if you dont want to wait, try asking in official discord.js server

Comment: link: https://discord.com/invite/djs
they should be able to help you (or direct you to a general js server where you can get help)

Comment: @TYPICALNINJA no worries, ill wait for you :)

Comment: hmm, i think i should just help you with your current stuff related to your question and not go further, anyway, for now just keep the setup your have, anyway, it reacts with all the emojis?

Comment: @TYPICALNINJA sorry for the late response haha, yes the bot reacts with the all the emojis, including the custom emojis. however, the bot only assigns 2 roles out of the 5 listed

Comment: on bot of the events, add `console.log(reaction)` and try, i want to see what they send, i should be able to help you fix with those data returned from the console.logs (hopefully)

Comment: @TYPICALNINJA this is what was shown (its too long so ill split the comments)

Comment: (node:7660) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: reaction is not defined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\nub\Desktop\bot\commands\reactionrole.js:91:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Comment: (node:7660) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: (node:7660) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: grateful to you for helping me out lol

Comment: hmm thats a error lol, you sure that what was logged from `console.log(reaction)` ?

Comment: yep that was @TYPICALNINJA, without `console.log(reaction)` nothing pops up

Comment: okay ill try out ur exact code and try to find something, should not take long as i have the same type of command handler you have, will post a answer if i find the issue (also this comment section is getting bit long)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with you getting the custom emojis, I guess you expected the `guild.emojis.cache.get("855257836106678282")` you did to return the emoji name, but it actually returns an object of the GuildEmoji class, as you can se [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildEmojiManager?scrollTo=cache), if you want the name then you need to add a `.name` after the get function, like this: `guild.emojis.cache.get("855257836106678282").name`.

[GuildEmoji class documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildEmoji)

Comment: ive tried this method, but the output that i got was the emoji id appearing in place of the emoji in the embed

Answer (score 0):

okay i think i know why your having a issue, so `reaction.emoji.name` returns the Unicode for built in emojis, and for customs one, the name of the emoji (duh lol)

and now `<something>.emojis.cache.get()` returns A [GuildEMoji](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildEmoji) object, (so from just this you can see the issue)

anyway i will explain it further

```
 if (reaction.emoji.name === EventsPingEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(EventsPing);
            }
```

EventsPingEmoji is a [GuildEMoji](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildEmoji) from `<something>.emojis.cache.get()` and `reaction.emoji.name` is a string, so your here comparing a string to a class (GuildEMoji object)

the simples way is adding `.name` to it as its a property of GuildEmoji,

the above code will be come

```
 if (reaction.emoji.name === EventsPingEmoji.name) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(EventsPing);
            }
```

```
reaction.emoji.name === EventsPingEmoji.name
                                        ^^^^^
```

Now try doing this to all ur if conditions, and post a comment if it did work :)